# docker entrypoint with multiple arguments

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am creating `Dockerfile` to run ethereum node on ubuntu container.

I want to run the below shell commands one after another sequentially in the container.

```
geth --datadir /home/ubuntu/eth-dev init /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/genesis.json 
geth --networkid 45634 --verbosity 4  --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 console 2>> /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/eth.log
```

I have create below Entrypoint in the Dockerfile which I believe incorrect.

```
 ENTRYPOINT ["geth", "--datadir /home/ubuntu/eth-dev", "init /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/genesis.json", "--networkid 45634", "--verbosity 4", "--ipcdisable", "--rpc", "--port 30301", "--rpcport 8545", "--rpcaddr 0.0.0.0", "console 2>> /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/eth.log"]
```

can anyone correct the `ENTRYPOINT` for the above shell command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the two commands in a shell script, `COPY` the shell script in the Dockerfile, then use that shell script as the entrypoint.

docker-entrypoint.sh:

```
geth --datadir /home/ubuntu/eth-dev init /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/genesis.json 
geth --networkid 45634 --verbosity 4  --ipcdisable --rpc --port 30301 --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 console 2>> /home/ubuntu/eth-dev/eth.log
```

Dockerfile:

```
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Be sure to `chmod +x` the script, either before copying or in a `RUN` command in the Dockerfile.